# Installing Ruby Gems without access to the official repository

Tags: rubygems

I'm connected to the internet using a proxy script in my office. As a result my
command prompt (Win XP) doesn't connect and I can access net only using the
browser.

Is there some I can install some ruby gems that I need manually - without using

```sh
gem install 'abc'
```

Or is there a way I can get my command prompt to connect to the internet.
Although my IE settings do use the script, I still cant get the CMD to connect.

Comment: Hello, If I have so many gem files in a directory, how can I install all gems in one command without specifying their names separately?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same problem when working on a confined environment. A nice workaround is to download the gem that you are interested in a usb stick and then install it manually.

This is the website where you can find all available ruby gems. [Ruby gems download](http://rubygems.org/pages/download). Find the one you are interested and download it.

Then move the gem in a directory of your choice and cd into that from the command prompt.
I am using `C:/ruby193/bin/pony-1.4.gem`

Let's say that the gem we are interested in is the pony gem (smtp email).

Just type `gem install pony-1.4.gem`

and you should get it installed manually unless you have a restricted acc with not adequate administrative privileges.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use --local and an absolute path. ie: `gem install --local C:\Ruby200\bin\sass-3.3.9.gem`

Comment: @mburn7 I tried `gem install --local C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby-termios-0.9.6.gem` but it gave me error: `Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby-termios-0.9.6.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for termios.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.You may need configuration options`

Answer (score 7):

```
gem install --force --local *.gem
```

http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network

Comment: really stupidly answer. if i store it in h:\a\b\c\d\e\f your command will find it? i saw your answer in this link before but cant understand how to install it.

Comment: @Amir The help page says you can change your directory before install command.