# Install Specific version gems on shared server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, hosting, web-hosting

I want to install ruby on rails application(fedena) on cpanel, it is version specific. I  have a shared server and they have some other gem versions. How to sort it out?

I tried to change gem path so that all the gems are accessed from home(root).but not sure how to do that. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778804/installing-ruby-gems-manually/10386302#10386302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into RVM, specifically gemsets, it is made exactly for what you describe.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-use-rvm/

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/