# Ruby on Rails, could not find a valid gem 'rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed ruby and updated ruby gems, now I want to download rails 3.2.13.
I write gem install rails  -v 3.2.13 (I need this version)
I have this error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 3.2.13), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect SYSCA
LL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (https://rubygems.org/s
pecs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

I read on internet that maybe downloading gem httpclient it could work, but I did not manage to download it (another error)
Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Get a connection that works? Did you try it again? Do you get the same error? Do other gems work?

Comment: Is it a internet connection problem? Yes other gems worked (jquery for instance) I've been able to download it

Comment: see if you can get this to work  "wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/rails-3.2.13.gem"

Comment: The issue most likely is with your internet connection. If you see this issue again, tried `gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: sounds like a debian server

Answer (score 66):

do this:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

then answer y for

```
Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]
```

lastly,

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix the SSL problem instead of working around it?

Comment: updating the certificates? I haven't tried it though since it looks a bit complicated for a newbie like me. Here's one that I found: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/osx-ssl-certs

Comment: @winmwx i face  this  issue...  no such name (http://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/activesupport-5.0.0.1.gemspec.rz   any idea

Answer (score 8):

I had a similiar error.

Try in your Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Instead of:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

That solved my problem...

Comment: Thanks for the trick! Seems like the simplest solution out of all the ones that I've read.

Answer (score 3):

> see if you can get this to work "wget rubygems.org/downloads/rails-3.2.13.gem"

That worked for me, but Vimsha did not explain how to install the gem once you've downloaded it.  It's quite easy:

```
gem install rails-3.2.13.gem
```

installs the gem and other gems that it depends on.

This is where I got that information from:

[Installing Ruby Gems manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778804/installing-ruby-gems-manually)

Answer (score 1):

The answer and methodology can be found on http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Skip to "INSTALLING USING UPDATE PACKAGES (NEW)" and follow the instructions

Newest RubyGem can be found at https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Comment: Even if that link has a correct answer to the question, please do elaborate on the main parts of that article and how that would contribute as an answer to the original post, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but turns out I had a proxy setup but I was trying to download gems from a proxyless network

First, Detect if you have any proxy setup. Do

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

If this command prints something on STDOUT on the terminal e.g. in my case

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.abcde.ac.za:80/
https_proxy=https://proxy.abcde.ac.za:80/
```

Do

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

This unsets the proxy environment variables to null so when you do **env | grep -i proxy** there should be no output.

Now run

```
gem install [gemname]
```