# Gem install rails doesn't work with Ruby 2.1.5 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have already tried the `gem install rails` on two different Windows 7 machines.
Ruby version installed 2.1.5
When I run `gem source` in command line I get https://rubygems.org
But when I try to run `gem install rails` I get the following error:

=================

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

====================================================

Is there a problem with the rubygems.org website ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does one of these answers help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944224/ruby-on-rails-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails

Comment: Running gem source -a http://rubygems.org in the command line and after 'gem install rails' installs the rails but I get some warning and rake gem is not installed even when trying to do it via 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'' as suggested in the warning message. Do you know why it's happening?

Comment: Also 'running rails' server after semi-successful rails installation and scaffolding the app with 'rails new appname' results in the following warning: "Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x64-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine" - needless to say rails server doesn't start.

Comment: Which warnings appear during installation of rails? Theses are too few information to help you.

Comment: When I changed gem source from https://rubygems.org to http://rubygems.org and run 'gem install rails' it installed all the way through and then showed the following warning: "Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org'L SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) 34 gems installed" but then when running 'rails -v' it shows DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle and in the next line Rails 4.2.0 , Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

For ruby version 2.1.5 we need rails version >3.2 and <5.0.
Try installing rails using below command for rails version 4.0.

```
gem install rails --version=4.0
```

And check rails -version, if it is changed to this one and run the server using below command.

```
rails server
```