# "The gem ... has been deleted. It was installed at" Error. Bundle install doesn't install gems. How to re-install gems?

Tags: bundler, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to build capybara-webkit on XP. I follow [this instruction](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit). I says:

```
8) Clone latest version of capybara-webkit from Github:

 $ git clone git://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git

9) Bundle/Install capybara-webkit version:

 $ cd ruby193\capybara-webkit
 $ bundle install
```

I did so at the first time. It installed some gems. Then I followed the instruction steps but couldn't build capybara-webkit. So to begin one more time, I deleted all the gems that were installed manually. Now I follow all the same steps but `bundle install` doesn't work any more. I says that all the gems are present:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>cd capybara-webkit

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using addressable (2.3.2)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using appraisal (0.4.0)
Using mime-types (1.22)
Using nokogiri (1.5.9)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using xpath (2.0.0)
Using capybara (2.1.0)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using capybara-webkit (1.0.0) from source at .
Using ffi (1.2.0)
Using childprocess (0.3.6)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2)
Using websocket (1.0.6)
Using libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)
Using subexec (0.0.4)
Using mini_magick (3.2.1)
Using multi_json (1.5.0)
Using rack-protection (1.3.2)
Using rspec-core (2.6.4)
Using rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
Using rspec (2.6.0)
Using rubyzip (0.9.9)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.27.2)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sinatra (1.3.5)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But now I check these gems with `bundle show` but it says they all were deleted:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show sinatra
The gem sinatra has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.5

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show selenium-webdriver
The gem selenium-webdriver has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show mini_magick
The gem mini_magick has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.2.1
```

How it can be that `bundle install` says they are present but `bundle show` says they are deleted? So `bundle install` doesn't work any more. How may I again use `bundle install` to install these gems again?

Comment: Very weird! I really cannot understand why it shows the gems as deleted. If you want to install your gems manually I think I've got a solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778804/installing-ruby-gems-manually/10386302#10386302

Answer (score 10):

This solved it for me: ["gem install" and "bundle install" do not install gem dependencies after manual gem deletion. How to inform Rubygems that gems were deleted manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474664/gem-install-and-bundle-install-do-not-install-gem-dependencies-after-manual)

(Delete the .gemspec files for the gems you have removed).