# "gem install" and "bundle install" do not install gem dependencies after manual gem deletion. How to inform Rubygems that gems were deleted manually?

Tags: rubygems

I was trying to build capybara-webkit on XP. I followed [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) instruction. It says to do `bundle install`:

```
 $ cd ruby193\capybara-webkit
 $ bundle install
```

This command installed many gems. Unfortunately I couldn't build capybara-webkit so I manually deleted all the gems it installed. After it I have problems with `gem install` and `bundle install` - these commands consider deleted gems as installed on my computer and do not install them if they are dependencies of some other gems I want to install now.

Please see an example. I do `bundle install` for `capybara-webkit` and it says that all the gems are present:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using addressable (2.3.2)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using appraisal (0.4.0)
Using mime-types (1.22)
Using nokogiri (1.5.9)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using xpath (2.0.0)
Using capybara (2.1.0)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using capybara-webkit (1.0.0) from source at .
Using ffi (1.2.0)
Using childprocess (0.3.6)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2)
Using websocket (1.0.6)
Using libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)
Using subexec (0.0.4)
Using mini_magick (3.2.1)
Using multi_json (1.5.0)
Using rack-protection (1.3.2)
Using rspec-core (2.6.4)
Using rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
Using rspec (2.6.0)
Using rubyzip (0.9.9)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.27.2)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sinatra (1.3.5)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But now I check these gems with `bundle show` and it says they all have been deleted:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show sinatra
The gem sinatra has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.5

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show selenium-webdriver
The gem selenium-webdriver has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\capybara-webkit>bundle show mini_magick
The gem mini_magick has been deleted. It was installed at:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.2.1
```

It looks like Rubygems somehow somewhere remembers that gems were installed and considers that they are still present. It seems that gems should be deleted only by `gem uninstall` command and not manually.

Is there a way to clear Rubygems cache? How to inform Rubygems that some gems were deleted manually and so that it should consider them as uninstalled now?

Answer (score 26):

After deleting the gem manually, Delete the gemspec file for that gem present at "C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\specifications". Then try bundle install.

Comment: ...or, if using RVM, delete the gemspec for that file at `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-X/specifications/`

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer comes very late but, having had the same problem myself, here is what worked for me; for anyone who may need it.

If you want to reinstall any gem you had manually removed, you will have to remove any reference to it in the directories in `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-X/` and then run `bundle install`. If you had manually deleted all of your gems, deleting everything in the `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-X/` directory and running `bundle` would reinstall them all.

Comment: the reference that had me stuck was in `/specifications/` for what it's worth

Comment: this worked for me. bundle show your_gem_name, go that directory and check the specifications folder, remove the gemspec and bundle update works fine

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had made a Gemfile in a directory and was doing a bundle install and I happened to deleted gem manually on os x due to which I was not able to install the gem again.

```
 1. gem list | grep your_gem_name
 2. uninstall your_gem_name
 3. removed Gemfile.lock
 4. bundle install from my Gemfile location
```

Answer (score 1):

For bundler v2.0 and before run:

```
bundle install --force
```

For v2.1 and after run:

```
bundle install --redownload
```

This will reinstall all gems, but keep versions.

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't higher, it worked like a charm.