# rails offline installation in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to install ruby on rails in **offline** mode (i.e. without internet connection). So I downloaded railsinstaller-3.2.0.exe from http://railsinstaller.org/en and installed it. By the end, I had ruby installed but in order to have rails installed I ran

```
gem install rails
```

and faced these errors: (meaning command needs internet connection)

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
        unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method 'invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I mean is there any solution like downloading gems with another computer connected to internet and then copying files in the proper location in the installed directory of gems.

Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: because gem has dependencies, so it try to get them

Answer (score 1):

As said in a comment, it's a gem (lib) dependency issue.

You might want to look into installing the [bundler](http://bundler.io/) gem library to manage dependencies for you, with bundler you would just have to run, bundle install and it would download all the required gems for you including any gem dependencies.

You can install bundler simply, just run

```
gem install bundler
```

Then in your rails project directory, just run bundle install.

Often to run a project (like rails for example) you might have to start it with

```
bundle exec rails start
```

To install Gem's on a non-internet connect computer you might want to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386302/3536548) on just that problem.

> [This is the website](https://rubygems.org/) where you can find all available ruby gems. Ruby
>   gems download. Find the one you are interested and download it.
>
> Then move the gem in a directory of your choice and cd into that from
>   the command prompt. I am using C:/ruby193/bin/pony-1.4.gem
>
> Let's say that the gem we are interested in is the pony gem (smtp
>   email).
>
> Just type gem install pony-1.4.gem
>
> and you should get it installed manually unless you have a restricted
>   acc with not adequate administrative privileges.

You can also refer to the [official documentation](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network) on the matter.

Comment: I know that this is just about dependencies, but suppose there is no internet connection. So the command you said "gem install bundler" also needs internet connection.

Comment: Well, sadly in that instance there's not a lot you can do (though correct me if I'm wrong). You could run your own gem server on a local machine with the common gems you normally use installed to it so if you can't connect to the internet you would have access to at least the bear minimum you need to get started. Bundler is just a wrapper with dependency management and environment execution for projects but it still uses `gem ` to install and since `gem` needs the internet, so does bundler. That said, you only need to install any gem once, after that it's freely available to any other project

Comment: I think you misunderstood something here and it's that I've got two computers one of them offline and one of them online. My question (now more precise) is that can I use my online computer system (i.e. download any gems needed to my rails project) and then transfer them using a USB cable to the offline computer system.

Comment: Truly I had downloaded lot of gems including rails and railties and then copied them all into the gems directory but using command "rails -v" I see that my system does not recognize those gems copied (The system cannot find the path specified). What can I do now?

Comment: Sounds like a pathing issue for bin files, did you uses the information from the official documentation?  Did you go to the dir where the gems are located and run `gem install --force --local *.gem` ? Copy & pasting is not enough, you need to tell ruby gems that the files exist so it can register them internally.